# How to do SQL calculations based from different rows with the same ID2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres database in AWS and creating some views with calculations.

I have multiple rows with the same ID but different Units and Subunits. I would like to get a Sum based on `Value_1` and `Value_2` in the SUM column.

`Value_1` and `Value_2` are always identical within the same ID but sometimes they are NULL.

I need a formula to calculate the SUM based on the ID.
The SUM will be identical for all the rows with the same ID.

Input:

| ID | unit | sub_unit | value_1 | value_2 | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | NULL | 10 | NULL |
| 1 | A | 2 | NULL | 10 | NULL |
| 1 | A | 3 | NULL | 10 | NULL |
| 1 | A | 4 | NULL | 10 | NULL |
| 1 | B | 1 | 5 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | B | 2 | 5 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | B | 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | B | 4 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I have tried with this query but since the values are in different rows it results always in NULL

```
SELECT
    ID,
    unit, sub_unit,
    value_1, value_2,
    value_1 * value_2 AS sum
FROM 
    t1
```

I'm not sure what would be best practice to solve this problem.

Should I try to fill all the NULL fields with one of the values? This should result in giving me the SUM for each row (SUM will be the same for each row with the same ID)

How can I get the first not NULL value from a column based on an ID and fill the other fields with the same ID with this value?

Maybe something like this:

| ID | unit | sub_unit | value_1 | value_2 | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | A | 3 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | A | 4 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | B | 2 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | B | 3 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | B | 4 | 5 | 10 | 50 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow why your sum and other columns should be the way they are (such as val1 is same for all), but this solution returns your desired output:

```
create table t1 (
  id integer, 
  unit varchar(1), 
  sub_unit integer, 
  value_1 integer, 
  value_2 integer
  );

insert into t1 values 
(1, 'A', 1, NULL, 10),
(1, 'A', 2, NULL, 10),
(1, 'A', 3, NULL, 10),
(1, 'A', 4, NULL, 10),
(1, 'B', 1, 5, NULL),
(1, 'B', 2, 5, NULL),
(1, 'B', 3, NULL, NULL),
(1, 'B', 4, NULL, NULL);
```

---

```
select 
 id, 
 unit, 
 sub_unit, 
 max(value_1) over (partition by id) as value_1, 
 max(value_2) over (partition by id) as value_2, 
 max(value_1) over (partition by id) *
 max(value_2) over (partition by id) as sum_col
from t1;
```

| id | unit | sub_unit | value_1 | value_2 | sum_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | A | 3 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | A | 4 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | B | 1 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | B | 2 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | B | 3 | 5 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | B | 4 | 5 | 10 | 50 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/egpmrXkmAUrY8a643RxQ1e/0)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), straightforward and easy to read.

```sql
select id, unit, sub_unit, 
  first_value(value_1) over (partition by id order by value_1 nulls last) value1,
  first_value(value_2) over (partition by id order by value_2 nulls last) value2,
  sum(value_1) over (partition by id) + sum(value_2) over (partition by id) "sum"
from the_table;
```

[DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g498oMhxjNcnSB5DQR45vN/2)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work

```
WITH ValueFill AS (
SELECT
    ID,
    unit,
    sub_unit,
    COALESCE(value_1, value_2) AS filled_value
FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
ID,
unit,
sub_unit,
value_1,
value_2,
filled_value,
SUM(filled_value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS sum
FROM
ValueFill;
```